# how to add text to a dataGridView cell in different form c#

Tags: c#, button, text, datagridview

I have 2 forms in my application, one contains a `dataGridView` with `button cell` and the other one contains a `button`. I want to add a text to the text in the cell from the button click. For example: i click on the button cell that contains the text "David" and it launches the second form. Then on button click in 2nd form, i want to modify the text in the cell to become "David    X". I tried writing a code but it showed an error.

this is my code so far:

```
namespace Top_Shine
{
public partial class Form3 : Form
{
    public Form3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    Top_Shine_Form tsf = new Top_Shine_Form();

    public static string passingX;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        passingX = tsf.dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString() + "    X";
        this.Close();
    }
}
}
```

how can i do this the right way?
thanks.

Comment: Next time please show your error code. So we can analyse it easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public partial class Form3 : Form
{
    public Form3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public Top_Shine_Form Tsf;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Tsf.dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value += "    X";
        this.Close();
    }
}

public partial class Top_Shine_Form : Form
{
    ...

    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        var form3 = new Form3();
        form3.Tsf = this;
        form3.ShowDialog();
    }

    ...
}
```

1. Use the right form.
2. Assign back the new value to cell.

Comment: the dataGridView and the button are not on the same form

Comment: yes, therefore you need to pass your parent form to child form.

Comment: Oh I didn't see it before the edit. But thank you so much. You have no Idea how many issues this edit solved.